# What To create Multiple form with multistep in php on single page

Tags: javascript, php, forms, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons, upon click on each of them a form will appear, and inside each form 3 step will be there.I created one form with multisteps on radio button click. But I am having trouble in creating the other two.Please help me out

Comment: What kind of trouble. Show us your code otherwise we cannot possibly know what's wrong

Comment: step by step i ll show you... what i have done

Comment: <input id="id_radio1" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio1" />I am Regular Travellor<input id="id_radio2" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio2" style="margin-left:205px;"/>
<input id="id_radio3" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio3" style="margin-left:205px;" />I am Open Travellor

Comment: three radio buttons .... on click first first form will appear...and other two hides

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the information, rather than using comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a basic structure so that when you click on form 1 radio button then form 1 main will open and same process will be for form 2 and form 3.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .dsp_none
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<input type="radio" class="form1" name="form1"/>Form1 <br>
<input type="radio" class="form2" name="form1" />Form2 <br>
<input type="radio" class="form3" name="form1" />Form3 <br>
<div class="form1_form dsp_none">
    This is form1
</div>
<div class="form2_form dsp_none">
    This is form2
</div>
<div class="form3_form dsp_none">
    This is form3
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('document').ready(function(){
        jQuery('.form1').click(function(){
            jQuery('.form1_form').css('display','block');
            jQuery('.form2_form').css('display','none');
            jQuery('.form3_form').css('display','none');
        });
        jQuery('.form2').click(function(){
            jQuery('.form2_form').css('display','block');
            jQuery('.form3_form').css('display','none');
            jQuery('.form1_form').css('display','none');
        });
        jQuery('.form3').click(function(){
            jQuery('.form3_form').css('display','block');
            jQuery('.form1_form').css('display','none');
            jQuery('.form2_form').css('display','none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Only you need to paste your code that you have created for one multi-step form within div which class is form1_form, form2_form, form3_form. and change class accordingly of your multistep form.